# Choosing entities for a database

Tags: database, entity-relationship

There are three kinds of people in a database, `member`, `volunteer` and `requester`.

Most of the `volunteers` are `members` and half of the `requesters` are `members`.

`volunteer` has some attributes that `member` doesn't have.

If a `requester` is not a `member`, only basic information can be put in the database. And they may become `member` later.

Anyone can be `requester` and `volunteer`, so, yes, a user can be both a `requester`, `volunteer` and `member` at same time. A user payed membership fee can be a `member`, once he made a `request`, he is a `requester`. And he can choose to be a `volunteer`. If a member did nothing, he is just member.

How should I choose entities?

Should I make them three entities or put them in one entity, and set volunteer and requester as two attributes?

Thanks

Comment: can a user be both a `requester` and `volunteer`? Can a user be just a `client`, without any sub-type?

Comment: It would also be useful if you described what the use cases are, without focusing on the DB. How do the three entities interact?

Comment: @tompave  `client`  may be confusing, I will use  `member`  instead of  `client` . Anyone can be  `requester`  and  `volunteer` , so, yes, a user can be both a  `requester`  and  `volunteer` , but can also not a  `member` . A user payed membership fee can be a  `member` , once he made a request, he is a   `requester ` . And he can choose to be a  `volunteer` . If a member did nothing, he is just member. I dont know if I make sense..

Comment: Sorry, I think it's not very clear yet. You said: "(...) but can also not a member.", but then it seems that a user can actually be all three at the same time. Also, can you add this explanation to the main body of the question?

Comment: Yes, they can be all three at same time. When a user sign up a membership, he becomes a member. When a user made a request, he is a requester, even he is not member, his basic information should be put into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about having a `users` table that contains all generic data, and then tables for the "roles", that contain role-specific data and that can be linked to the users:

```
user:
    - id
    - name
    - email
    - member_id
    - volunteer_id
    - requester_id

client
    - id
    - data

volunteer
    - id
    - data

requester
    - id
    - data
```

Then, if you are representing the rows with an object-oriented abstraction, your `User` objects can have this method:

```
// C-style pseudocode

boolean isVolunteer() {
    !!self.volunteer_id;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create 4 tables:

```
persons (person_id PK, first_name, last_name)
members (person_id PK/FK)
volunteers (person_id PK/FK)
requesters (person_id PK/FK)
```

Add common attributes to the persons table, and role-specific attributes to the relevant table.

Comment: Thanks, but many instances in these tables are same, will it increase redundancy?

Comment: This is a typical subtyping pattern.  As long as you normalize your data, no redundant facts will be recorded.  Because all 4 tables use the same primary key, this is actually less redundant than designs which create new identifiers and columns for every role.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have several shared attributes among your entities, some occur on more than, some occur exclusively on others. It's not exactly a beautiful solution but seems to fit your problem, it's called Single Table Inheritance in JPA jargon. Despite the fact the article is written focusing on Java, it can be achieved with other technologies.

[JPA Single Table Inheritance Example](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/05/14/jpa-single-table-inheritance-example/)

Comment: Thanks. But  in this example, the instances in each sub-tables are different. In my case, for example, `member` and `volunteer` can have same instances,